# Solving a nonlinear integral equation for a distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions, functional-equations

I have an equation of a probability distribution function $F$ on $[0,\infty)$, $$F(x)=e^{-\eta [1-\int_0^x F(x-y)g(y)\mathrm{d}y]},\quad x\in[0,\infty), $$
where $g$ is a probability density function, also supported by $[0,\infty)$. I am trying to solve it for $F$, either analytically or numerically, but not sure how to start. For the numerical solution, I tried an ad hoc approach where $F$ is approximated by a linear combination of some distribution functions (e.g., $\exp(-\eta)$ plus a linear combination of the gamma distribution functions with shape parameters $1,2,\ldots,n$), but the resulting approximate solution is not always increasing and some times it goes above 1. I wonder if anyone can explain to me how to do it properly or point me to the suitable literature. Thanks a lot.